# how to crawl a javascript page whose content name is defined by a reference?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

The website is http://www.landchina.com/default.aspx?tabid=351
I'm sorry it's in Chinese but it may not concerns with the topic.

At present I can fetch all the contents in this page and I want to go to next page now.

The numbers in the bottom of the page indicate the pages. Currently I am in page 1 and I want to go to page 2. (I'm sorry that I have no reputation to post images here.)

However, when I tried to get the url of next page. it seems to be a dynamic page.

```
<td align="left" class="pager" valign="bottom" style="width:60%"> 
<a disabled="disabled" style="margin-right:5px;">首页</a>
<a disabled="disabled" style="margin-right:5px;">上页</a>
<span style="color: red;font-weight: bold;margin-right: 5px;">1</span>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="QueryAction.GoPage('TAB',2)" style="margin-right:5px;">2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="QueryAction.GoPage('TAB',3)" style="margin-right:5px;">3</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="QueryAction.GoPage('TAB',4)" style="margin-right:5px;">4</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="QueryAction.GoPage('TAB',5)" style="margin-right:5px;">5</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="QueryAction.GoPage('TAB',6)" style="margin-right:5px;">6</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="QueryAction.GoPage('TAB',7)" style="margin-right:5px;">7</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="QueryAction.GoPage('TAB',8)" style="margin-right:5px;">8</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="QueryAction.GoPage('TAB',9)" style="margin-right:5px;">9</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="QueryAction.GoPage('TAB',10)" style="margin-right:5px;">10</a>
```

When I tried to use selenium to get the content, I cant't handle such javascript code because the name of this button is in the form of a reference. How to go to the next page in such situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`find_element_by_link_text()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_link_text) should work:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('2').click()
```

Of course, in you case `2` would be calculated dynamically, e.g.:

```
cur_page = 1
while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_link_text(str(cur_page)).click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break

    # logic

    cur_page += 1
```